# Django REST: ¿Cómo comparto request.session['clave'] entre varias vistas?

Tags: django, session, djangorestframework

Quiero comprobar si un usuario ha iniciado sesión guardando un JWT en `request.session["token"]`. En la vista `login`, el `print(request.session["token"])` funciona, pero en la vista `getUser` no. ¿Cómo hago que la variable de sesión esté disponible en todas las vistas?

El error que me da es un `keyError` en el "token".

He probado con `request.session.modified = true` después de asignar "token" pero tampoco funciona.

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
  if request.data["usuario"] and request.data["pwd"]:
    try:
      user_item = User.objects.get(usuario=request.data["usuario"])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return Response({'errors': 'Usuario no existe'}, status=402)
    usr_pwd = request.data["pwd"]
    bd_pwd = user_item.pwd
    if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_pwd.encode('utf-8'),bd_pwd.encode('utf-8')):
      token = jwt.encode({'user': request.data["usuario"]}, 'palacin', algorithm='HS256')
      request.session["token"] = token
      print(request.session["token"]) # <-- ESTE PRINT FUNCIONA
      return Response(200)
    else:
      return Response({'errors': 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.'}, status=401)
  else:
    return Response({'errors': 'Usuario y/o contraseña no especificados'}, status=400)

@api_view(['POST'])
def getUser(request):
  print(request.session["token"]) # <-- ESTE PRINT NO FUNCIONA
  '''if "token" in request.session:
    return Response(jwt.decode(request.session["token"], 'palacin', algorithms=['HS256']))
  else:
    return Response({'errors': 'Sesión no iniciada'}, status=403)'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondo porque no tengo puntos para comentar.
Debes asegurarte de tener en tu settings.py instalada la aplicación

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ... 
]
```

Y el middleware siguiente también

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Tu código se ve correcto, deberia funcionarte, pero deberías cambiar

```
print(request.session["token"])
```

por

```
print(request.session.get("token"))
```

Para evitar una posible exception en caso de que esa entrada en el diccionario no se haya creado aún

Comment: Ya tenía eso en el settings.py